# Getting undefined when trying to send select value to other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small JavaScript issue.

I have the following form:

```
<form method="get" name="basic" id="basicId" action="/page2"> 
     <select id="activity" name="activity" class="form-control inputbox">
          <option value="default" class="activities">Select value from dropdown:</option>
          <option value="a" class="tests">A</option>
          <option value="b" class="tests">B</option>
          <option value="c" class="tests">C</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" placeholder="Search">Search</button>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is to `get the value` from the `select tag` and use it in `page2`.
For example, is option is A, the value should be `="a"`. 
I want to use the `value="a"` in page2.
`document.getElementById("output")`: here i want to print the result in page2.

What I've tried to do in the second page:

```
<script>
var select = document.getElementById("activity");
var e = select.options[select.SelectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = e;
<!-- This doesn't show anything. -->

var test = document.getElementsbyName("activity").values;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = test;
<!-- The output is: function values() { [native code] } -->


var test = document.getElementsByName("activity").value;
document.getElementById("opinion").innerHTML = test;
<!-- The output is: undefined -->

</script>
```

So basically, getting the select element by ID or by Name doesn't work.
Getting the select element ID.value doesn't work.
Getting the select element by the index doesn't work.

Any ideas? I've literally tried anything.
Am I writing the code in the wrong place?

Do I have to send this information through the server-side?
P.S.: I am writing the app in Node.js and Express and I'm using handlebars.

Kind regards,
G.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I add a class for each option, and use: GetElementsByClassName, I will get the output: [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: Do you want the value of the select each time it get changed ? \

Comment: If it is possible, yes. I am trying to get the value of the select, and then do some if statements. If I'm going back to the index page and select B, i will need value="b" in the next page.

Comment: 'to other page' - meaning that you are navigating away from the current page and loading a completely different page?

Comment: Yes. I have the form in index.hbs, and I want to navigate to page2.hbs

Comment: As I navigate to the second page, I can see in the link activity=a or activity=b but I'm not sure how I can get that information and to use it properly

Comment: @GabrielCretu Check the answer

Comment: @SatyamPathak I've tried. Doesn't show anything in the next page..

Comment: @SatyamPathak Yess, I can get the url and I can see that value in the url. After that, I have to check if in the url activity=a, I suppose?

Comment: @SatyamPathak Problem Solved. I will post my solution as a comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
If you want to get the value to other page, you need to fetch it from `url`  as whole new page  get rendered and your old values  will not exist exist.

If you are having your values in `url` just fetch it by this

```
let url = window.location
```

I assume, you are trying to get the value of `dropdown`

`select` has always the `value attribute` to it which actually is the value you select from dropdown

You just need to look for the `value` of select whenever you want the selected option.

Here in your case just attach a `onchange listener` to select, which triggers whenever the value of select get changed

```js
var select = document.getElementById("activity");
var mySelectValue = select.value // set the default value
select.onchange = function() {
 console.log(select.value)
  mySelectValue = select.value // update whenever value get changed or new value chosen
}

// Do whatever you want to do with selectvalue
```

```html
<form method="get" name="basic" id="basicId" action="/page2"> 
     <select id="activity" name="activity" class="form-control inputbox">
          <option value="default" class="activities">Select value from dropdown:</option>
          <option value="a" class="tests">A</option>
          <option value="b" class="tests">B</option>
          <option value="c" class="tests">C</option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit" id="searchBtn" placeholder="Search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I have fetched  the link and I tried to check if the activity = something.

example down below:

```
if(url.href.indexOf("activity=a") > -1){
    activity = "a"
}
document.getElementById("opinion").innerHTML = activity;
```

Of course, in the page2, I can see "a" as a result which is great! :)